# How is this an eigenvalue problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In a [paper](http://www.4shared.com/office/cIdBPJR5ce/Vibration_of_nonlocal_Timoshen.html) that I'm reading, the author mentions something of this sort:-

> ...we arrive at an eigenvalue problem defined by the following matrix
>   equation:
>
> $   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}    \sinh(\beta) & \sin(\gamma) 
>  \\    \beta \psi_\beta \sinh(\beta) & \gamma \psi_\gamma \sin(\gamma) \\
>  \end{array} } \right]  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}    C_2\\    C_4\\  
>  \end{array} } \right]
>  =0 $
>
> The eigenvalues are obtained by setting the determinant of the matrix
>   to $0$ and then solving the characteristic equation.
>   By solving the characteristic equation, one obtains $\sin(\gamma) = 0 \implies \gamma =n\pi $.

I admit I haven't had an introductory course in Linear Algebra yet, but I believe eigenvalues are $\lambda$ satisfying the matrix equation $Ax=\lambda x$, for some matrix $A$. But in the above case, the matrix equation is in the form $Ax=0$. Besides, obtaining $\sin(\gamma)=0$ is as simple as setting the determinant = $0$ (assuming that non-trivial solutions exist). How do eigenvalues and the characteristic equation come into the picture here?

Comment: I guess $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Yes, I see that. But why even consider $\lambda$ here then? Why bring in the concept of eigenvalues here? How does it fit?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to compute? $C_2$, $C_4$ or $\gamma$ and $\beta$? And also, are you asking here "Why not solve this as a system of equations"?

Comment: $\gamma$ and $\beta$. This is coming from a system of ODEs, whose general solution has $C_2$ and $C_4$ as two arbitrary constants.

Comment: Linear algebra is of tremendous importance and its language ties together a number of seemingly disparate areas of mathematics. When you ask "Why bring in the concept of eigenvalues here", it's like asking "Why mention the derivative when talking about the slope of $y=mx+b$"? Sure, the derivative isn't necessary at this point and I wouldn't mention it in pre-calculus. In a *calculus* class, however, it might very well serve to elevate the conversation.

Comment: @frabala: And I guess it's technically not solving as a system of equations, because I'm not trying to find $C_2$ and $C_4$. I'm just trying to gather sufficient information about $\beta$ and $\gamma$. I admit this is confusing without context. Would you have a look at the original paper, please? It's here: http://www.4shared.com/office/cIdBPJR5ce/Vibration_of_nonlocal_Timoshen.html

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Oh, I apologize if I sounded rude! But that wasn't my intention at all. You see, I'm very much interested in exactly how such seemingly disparate concepts are all interconnected, rather than dismissing the very idea of it. Learning this new language would expand my arsenal of solving such problems in the future. In fact, going by my way of solving it, I'm getting stuck terribly, and I was wondering if the author's method of eigenvalues can simplify it to a greater extent. But I'm just not familiar with it enough, and was simply asking around to see how it fits here.

Comment: @JobinIdiculla I didn't think you were rude at all!  Just curious, which is good. I think your question was perfectly natural.

Answer (score 2):

What I think is meant is something like this, with $B$ = your matrix, you can transform to an eigenvalue problem as follows
$$\begin{align}
B\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{0} \\
(B-I)\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{0}\\
(B-I)\mathbf{x} &= -\mathbf{x},\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{now set }A=I-B\\
A\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{x}
\end{align}$$

The standard way to transform from an eigenvalue problem to the characteristic equation is the opposite of this.
$$\begin{align}
A\mathbf{x} &= \lambda\mathbf{x}\\
A\mathbf{x} - \lambda\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{0}\\
(A-I\lambda)\mathbf{x} &= \mathbf{0}
\end{align}$$
You already have an $= \mathbf{0}$ equation so I must admit to wanting to have more information than "we arrive at an eigenvalue problem".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I slightly understand what was done, but I still don't get the whole picture. And I think you'd appreciate the context too. Could you have a look at pages 3-4 of the original paper here: http://www.4shared.com/office/cIdBPJR5ce/Vibration_of_nonlocal_Timoshen.html ?

Comment: @JobinIdiculla Thankyou it's interesting to see the context. I've only skimmed the paper, but in many physical systems, you can get a solution to your governing equations as a set of independent eigenfunctions. The precise weighting of each one is determined by the ICs or BCs. So it seems like the motivation for talking about the problem as an eigenvalue problem might be to relate it to the physical system. Here it seems like each eigenfunction is a vibration, and each eigenvalue is the _frequency_ of the corresponding vibration.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I still have yet to understand it fully, but now I know what I'm looking for.