Computing eigenvalues for specific initial conditions
Take the following equation $-x'' = \gamma x$ which has the known solution $$x = A\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}t ) + B \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}t).$$Now assume that $x(0) = x(\alpha)$ and $x'(0) = -x'(\alpha)$. I am looking for the eigenvalues $\gamma$.
Approach: I tried constructing the system that results from the two equations: $$\begin{cases}A = A\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha) + B\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha),\\
 B\sqrt{\gamma} = A\sqrt{\gamma}\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha) - B\sqrt{\gamma}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha),\end{cases}$$which can then be transformed into a matrix when solving for $A$ and $B$, $$M = \begin{bmatrix}1- \cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha) &  - \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha)\\ - \sqrt{\gamma} \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha) & \sqrt{\gamma}+ \sqrt{\gamma}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\alpha) 
\end{bmatrix}.$$ But this matrix has determinant zero. I am stuck now.
Question: How can I get the eigenvalue $\gamma$ from these conditions?

Is that not the matrix $M$ used to solve $ M[A,B]^t =[0,0]^t $? If so, it better have determinant $0$.

@Steen82. Well.. it is zero indeed. I thought this was the method to find $\gamma$? For more info https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676293/how-is-this-an-eigenvalue-problem?rq=1

The fact that $\det M(\gamma)=0$ for any $\gamma$ implies that any $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ is an eigenvalue of $-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$ with the given boundary conditions. Indeed, one can easily check that the functions below are nontrivial solutions to $-x''=\gamma x$ satisfying $x(0)=x(\alpha)$ and $x'(0)=-x'(\alpha)$:
$$
x_{\gamma}(t)=
\begin{cases}
\sin (\sqrt{\gamma}\,x)+\sin (\sqrt{\gamma}\,(\alpha-x))&\text{if $\gamma>0,\,\sqrt{\gamma}\neq \frac{2n\pi}{\alpha}\,(n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0})$,} \\
\cos\!\left(\frac{2n\pi x}{\alpha}\right)&\text{if $\sqrt{\gamma}=\frac{2n\pi}{\alpha}\,(n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0})$,} \\
1&\text{if $\gamma=0$}, \\
\sinh (\sqrt{-\gamma}\, x)+\sinh (\sqrt{-\gamma}\,(\alpha- x))&\text{if $\gamma<0$}.
\end{cases}
$$

This is exactly the answer that I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Expanding my comment here, since I think this is too long for a comment.
For any $\gamma$ and any $A,B$ the function $x=A\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}t)+B\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}t)$ is a solution to $-x''=\gamma x.$ Simply setting $A=B=0$ always solves your problem including the initial values.
Now, you can in a manner similar to my original answer, convert your initial values into matrix form and ask under which conditions that problem has non-zero solutions for $A,B.$ I think this is what you did, and you found the matrix has determinant zero, so non-zero solutions are possible.
My original point was that the determinant being zero, was a good thing. I interpreted your statement "But this matrix has determinant zero." to imply it was not desirable.
My previous expansion.
$$M\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}1- \cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) &  - \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta)\\ 
- \sqrt{\gamma} \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) & \sqrt{\gamma}+ \sqrt{\gamma}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Is the matrix form of the system
\begin{align*}
    A - A\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) - B\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) &= 0 \\
    -A\sqrt{\gamma} \sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta)+B\sqrt{\gamma}+ B\sqrt{\gamma}\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta) &=0
\end{align*}
Which rearranges to your system.
Let me solve this system. If $\gamma=0$ the system is $0=0,$ so any $A,B$ gives a solution. Assume $\gamma\neq 0$ and divide the second equation by $\sqrt{\gamma}.$ Let $c:=\cos\sqrt{\gamma}\beta)$, and $s:=\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}\beta).$ Then the matrix form is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1- c &  - s \\ 
- s & 1+c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
A \\ B 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}  
$$
If $c=1$, then $s=0$ and the equations are $0\cdot A = 0$ and  $2B=0$, so $A$ can be anything and $B=0.$ If $c=-1$ then the equations are $2A=0$ and $0\cdot B=0$ so $A=0$ and $B$ can be anything. If $c\neq \pm1$ then $s\neq 0.$ Multiplying the first row by $1+c$ and the second row by $-s$ we get the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
s^2 &  - s(1+c) \\ 
s^2 &  - s(1+c)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
A \\ B 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence, if $A$ is anything and $B=\tfrac{1+c}{c}A,$ then we have a solution for $A,B.$ The relationship between $A,B$ depends on $\gamma$ and on $\beta.$

Thank you for the attention but that has nothing to do with my question. I want to know how to find $\gamma$.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to find $\gamma$ based on the info in your problem.

If I may, can you elaborate on why is that?

Exactly. But lets forget about the $A = B = 0$ since they are not interesting. You mentioned that non-zero solutions are possible. Can I find them? I am essentially looking for an expression $\gamma$ equals to something so that $x = A\cos(\sqrt{\gamma}t) + B\sin(\sqrt{\gamma}t)$ is a non-trivial solution.

I added a solution for $A,B$ in terms of $\gamma, \beta.$

I am not accepting your answer because you are completely avoiding my question. Again, I appreciate your effort but that is not what I am looking for. Again, if you see the link in the comment section of the publication you can find in the grey area (the part that mentions the article) something of $\gamma = n\pi$. That's what I want but in my case.

That is your choice, I just proved you can't have what you want.
